# Ruby on Rails: accessing and expanding a SQL query via a model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The Ruby on Rails application I am working on has an `exchange_rate` table that I wish to access while  doing calculations to convert one currency to another.  The table looks like this:

```
id | base_currency_id | currency_id | exchange_rate |
---+------------------+-------------+---------------+
2  |                1 |           2 |        0.9345 |
3  |                1 |           3 |        0.5000 |
```

The `exchange_rate` model looks like this:

```
class ExchangeRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  validates :base_currency_id, :currency_id, :exchange_rate, presence: true
  ...
  def self.matching_exchange_rate(base_currency)
    ExchangeRate.where("base_currency_id = ?",base_currency)
  end 

  # Commented out as I can't get it to work yet:
  # def self.matching_exchange_rate (base_currency, target_currency_id)
  #  where("base_currency_id = ?",base_currency " and currency_id = ?",target_currency_id)
  # end
```

I have been invoking/calling the incomplete-but-working function `matching_exchange_rate` like this:

```
x_rate = ExchangeRate.matching_exchange_rate(user_currency_id)
puts "x_rate = " + x_rate.to_s
```

This displays in the log as:

```
x_rate = #<ExchangeRate::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000010b434c78>
```

I would love help with either of these questions:
(1) How do I change the `matching_exchange_rate` method so that it uses two input parameters?  I have tried a large number of different combinations--one of which is in the commented-out code above--but so far I have had no luck.
(2) How do I access the `exchange_rate` from return value? (e.g., the `ActiveRecord_Relation`)

Thanks in advance for any help,
Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to select `exchange_rate` with supplied condition as follows:

```
def self.matching_exchange_rate(base_currency, target_currency_id)
  where(
    "base_currency_id = ? and currency_id = ?", base_currency,target_currency_id
  ).pluck(
    'exchange_rate'
  ).first
end
```

The code above is replacement to your commented out method.  As far as the following output you've posted is concerned:

```
x_rate = #<ExchangeRate::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000010b434c78>
```

[`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  You could have used `first` method on your AR query to get reference to the first `ExchangeRate` record on which you could have called `exchange_rate` on as follows:

```
x_rate = ExchangeRate.matching_exchange_rate(user_currency_id).first.exchange_rate
puts "x_rate = " + x_rate.to_s
```

Comment: @user1854802, you're welcome. I'm glad the answer was helpful.